# How to Download Javascript Server Logs on Meteor Galaxy

Tags: meteor, meteor-galaxy

Well, that pretty much sums it up: how is it possible to download the file for the complete server log for a Meteor Galaxy project (all containers).  Using the GUI provided by Galaxy isn't adequate for searching large amounts of server log.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to download logs as well. I don't think there is any provision for that yet. Alternatively you can setup loggly or some other API based logging service and check out logs there. Initially I tried Loggly which did not persist logs long enough(in free account) for my requirement. So, I used AWS Cloudwatch APIs to write app logs. It provides a very basic console but was good enough for me in the given budget.